# How do I access the last string in a list of command line options passed in via main(String[] args)?

Tags: java, arrays, command-line-interface

I'm building a Java application that takes a varying number of command line options as input, with a file name consistently the last item. When I specify the argument index in the second line below (e.g. `args[2]`, everything does of course work correctly when I know the index ahead of time, but I'm having trouble coming up with the correct syntax for accessing the final item in a `String[]` when dealing with a file or even just a string as the input vs. an array of integers or something simpler for when that index number varies.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inFile = args.length-1;
```

Comment: Assuming `args` is not empty: `args[args.length - 1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
String inFile = args[args.length - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I realize this is a simple question, but I hope this makes other people's searches easier as I wasn't able to find this otherwise.

Comment: My pleasure.  Please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use

```
String inFile = args[args.length-1];
//array name    ^^^
//last index value   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are often needing this functionality you can encapsulate it into a method:

```
public static <T> T last(T[] them) {
    return them != null && them.length > 0 ? them[them.length - 1] : null;
}

public void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = last(args);
}
```

Comment: Fine but note that the null check is dead code as `String[] args` cannot be null in a main() method.

Comment: `null` can be an element in the array, so it shouldn't be returned as the "error" value. Better to throw `NullPointerException` if `them` is `null`, and `NoSuchElementException` if it is empty.